# What is the best practice to insert new entry with nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models:

This is the first:

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    owner: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

This is the second:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    comments: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
});
```

There are really a lot of comments. So, i add the id of each comment in the array of comment of owner. The goal is to create a simple function like "list my comments".
The comments are verry actually, i use this code to add new comment:

```
var comment = ...
comment.title = "title";
comment.owner = req.user
comment.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        ...
    else {
        User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }, function (err, tmpUser){
            tmpUser.comments.push(comment);
            tmpUser.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    ...
                else {
                    //END
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

How to optimise this code ? Is it possible to optimise directly the model ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply query the Comments collection? If you're worried about the performance when there are a lot of comments, you can (and should) index the owner field.

```
db.comments.ensureIndex( { owner: 1 } )
```

And then using mongoose:

```
Comment.find({ owner: req.user._id }, function(err, comments) {
  // do something with comments
});
```

Comment: where can i configure this index, is it possible in my nodejs project ? with mongoose, it's better to realise index in field level or schema level ? 
var animalSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
});

animalSchema.index({ name: 1, type: -1 }); // schema level
thank you !

Comment: If you add it to Mongoose, it will automatically call ensureIndex every time the app starts up. This is okay for development purposes but you don't want it in production. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes

If you have a large existing database, you should call in on the database directly and make sure to set `commentSchema.set('autoIndex', false);`